Unable to setup PIRANHA BY UBER to remove stale code in my demo application
I am trying to setup PIRANHA BY UBER on my local for a demo java (Java 8) application. I am not able to perform a remove the stale code by building it.
Demo Application:
@Controller
public class FlagController {
    boolean feature_flag_stale = false;

    public void executeFeature() {
        if (feature_flag_stale) {
            executeNewFeature();
        } else {
            executeOldFeature();
        }
    }
    private void executeNewFeature() {
        System.out.println("Executing the new feature...");
    }

    private void executeOldFeature() {
        System.out.println("Executing the old feature...");
    }
}

I want to remove this feature_flag_stale flag using PIRANHA.
I tried the following steps :

Clone the repository: git clone https://github.com/uber/piranha.git.
Navigate to the cloned directory: cd piranha
Build the project: cargo build --release (or cargo build --release --no-default
features for macOS)
The binary will be generated under target/release

Is anyone aware what should be the next steps to set it up on my local.
Has anyone tried it before using any other way?
